# Issues with keras ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (4,)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I am receiving the error above when running my keras CNN. The final layer of my model is created by the code

```
model.add(Dense(4,activation='softmax'))
```

and when I run `model.summary()`
it outputs
`dense_3 (Dense) (None, 4) 104`

I've checked the shape of my test and training data and they are both (N,4).

Any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: What loss are you using?

Comment: Yeah, try putting 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' under loss parameter in model.compile

Comment: This is what I am using to compile 
    model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam',metrics=['accuracy'])

Comment: In this case you have to use the categorical crossentropy loss, not the sparse one.

Comment: that worked! Thank you